# Redis creating new connections and dropping older connection every second

Tags: redis, connection, redisson

We have a **Redis cluster**(running in Sentinel mode) with 3 nodes and we are using **Redisson** (version 3.10.7) to interact with Redis.
We are facing an issue wherein the client application is not able to connect to the cluster. Continuously **older connections are being dropped and new connections are being created**. The same thing is happening every second. Below is the snapshot for the logger.

```
12:01:00.832 [redisson-netty-2-6] DEBUG org.redisson.connection.ClientConnectionsEntry - new connection created: RedisConnection@483495011 [redisClient=[addr=redis://10.79.9.163:6379], channel=[id: 0x767f3c87, L:/192.168.7.24:60173 - R:10.79.9.163/10.79.9.163:6379], command=null]
12:01:00.832 [redisson-netty-2-6] DEBUG org.redisson.connection.ClientConnectionsEntry - new connection created: RedisConnection@1510307492 [redisClient=[addr=redis://10.79.9.163:6379], channel=[id: 0xa8c01128, L:/192.168.7.24:60183 - R:10.79.9.163/10.79.9.163:6379], command=null]
12:01:00.832 [redisson-netty-2-6] DEBUG org.redisson.connection.ClientConnectionsEntry - new connection created: RedisConnection@425141862 [redisClient=[addr=redis://10.79.9.164:6379], channel=[id: 0x19afdfb8, L:/192.168.7.24:60199 - R:10.79.9.164/10.79.9.164:6379], command=null]
12:01:00.832 [redisson-netty-2-6] DEBUG org.redisson.connection.ClientConnectionsEntry - new connection created: RedisConnection@457747719 [redisClient=[addr=redis://10.79.9.164:6379], channel=[id: 0xf2431dfb, L:/192.168.7.24:60211 - R:10.79.9.164/10.79.9.164:6379], command=null]
12:01:00.832 [redisson-netty-2-6] DEBUG org.redisson.connection.ClientConnectionsEntry - new connection created: RedisConnection@1595469651 [redisClient=[addr=redis://10.79.9.164:6379], channel=[id: 0x3226faec, L:/192.168.7.24:60204 - R:10.79.9.164/10.79.9.164:6379], command=null]
12:01:00.922 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.redisson.client.handler.ConnectionWatchdog - reconnecting RedisConnection@541871189 [redisClient=[addr=redis://10.79.9.164:6379], channel=[id: 0x5396b42d, L:/192.168.7.24:59969 ! R:10.79.9.164/10.79.9.164:6379], command=CommandData [promise=RedissonPromise [promise=ImmediateEventExecutor$ImmediatePromise@3ecd3a79(failure: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException)], command=(PING), params=[], codec=org.redisson.client.codec.StringCodec]] to 10.79.9.164/10.79.9.164:6379 
12:01:00.929 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.redisson.client.handler.ConnectionWatchdog - reconnecting RedisConnection@495642036 [redisClient=[addr=redis://10.79.9.164:6379], channel=[id: 0xfa2f4f52, L:/192.168.7.24:59973 ! R:10.79.9.164/10.79.9.164:6379], command=CommandData [promise=RedissonPromise [promise=ImmediateEventExecutor$ImmediatePromise@28c788eb(failure: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException)], command=(PING), params=[], codec=org.redisson.client.codec.StringCodec]] to 10.79.9.164/10.79.9.164:6379 
12:01:00.931 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.redisson.client.handler.ConnectionWatchdog - reconnecting RedisConnection@169281839 [redisClient=[addr=redis://10.79.9.164:6379], channel=[id: 0xf365bc68, L:/192.168.7.24:59976 ! R:10.79.9.164/10.79.9.164:6379], command=CommandData [promise=RedissonPromise [promise=ImmediateEventExecutor$ImmediatePromise@6bd0d406(failure: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException)], command=(PING), params=[], codec=org.redisson.client.codec.StringCodec]] to 10.79.9.164/10.79.9.164:6379 
12:01:00.931 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.redisson.client.handler.ConnectionWatchdog - reconnecting RedisConnection@65640722 [redisClient=[addr=redis://10.79.9.165:6379], channel=[id: 0x03c68dcf, L:/192.168.7.24:59226 ! R:10.79.9.165/10.79.9.165:6379], command=CommandData [promise=RedissonPromise [promise=ImmediateEventExecutor$ImmediatePromise@520c88b3(failure: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException)], command=(PING), params=[], codec=org.redisson.client.codec.StringCodec]] to 10.79.9.165/10.79.9.165:6379 
12:01:00.932 [pool-2-thread-1] DEBUG org.redisson.client.handler.ConnectionWatchdog - reconnecting RedisConnection@1365249560 [redisClient=[addr=redis://10.79.9.165:6379], channel=[id: 0x0722fcc6, L:/192.168.7.24:59262 ! R:10.79.9.165/10.79.9.165:6379], command=CommandData [promise=RedissonPromise [promise=ImmediateEventExecutor$ImmediatePromise@50c8b29f(failure: java.util.concurrent.CancellationException)], command=(PING), params=[], codec=org.redisson.client.codec.StringCodec]] to 10.79.9.165/10.79.9.165:6379 
12:01:01.080 [redisson-netty-2-8] DEBUG org.redisson.connection.ClientConnectionsEntry - new connection created: RedisConnection@1230181180 [redisClient=[addr=redis://10.79.9.163:6379], channel=[id: 0x148352d3, L:/192.168.7.24:60224 - R:10.79.9.163/10.79.9.163:6379], command=CommandData [promise=RedissonPromise [promise=ImmediateEventExecutor$ImmediatePromise@19cb007f(incomplete)], command=(PING), params=[], codec=org.redisson.client.codec.StringCodec]]
12:01:01.082 [redisson-netty-2-5] DEBUG org.redisson.connection.ClientConnectionsEntry - new connection created: RedisConnection@1221343292 [redisClient=[addr=redis://10.79.9.163:6379], channel=[id: 0xc4ff65cd, L:/192.168.7.24:60229 - R:10.79.9.163/10.79.9.163:6379], command=CommandData [promise=RedissonPromise [promise=ImmediateEventExecutor$ImmediatePromise@1891a694(incomplete)], command=(PING), params=[], codec=org.redisson.client.codec.StringCodec]]
12:01:01.082 [redisson-netty-2-7] DEBUG org.redisson.connection.ClientConnectionsEntry - new connection created: RedisConnection@2036916006 [redisClient=[addr=redis://10.79.9.163:6379], channel=[id: 0xff04b8ab, L:/192.168.7.24:60223 - R:10.79.9.163/10.79.9.163:6379], command=CommandData [promise=RedissonPromise [promise=ImmediateEventExecutor$ImmediatePromise@1618e7eb(incomplete)], command=(PING), params=[], codec=org.redisson.client.codec.StringCodec]]
12:01:01.082 [redisson-netty-2-9] DEBUG org.redisson.connection.ClientConnectionsEntry - new connection created: RedisConnection@1460667823 [redisClient=[addr=redis://10.79.9.163:6379], channel=[id: 0xbdc0d69e, L:/192.168.7.24:60222 - R:10.79.9.163/10.79.9.163:6379], command=CommandData [promise=RedissonPromise [promise=ImmediateEventExecutor$ImmediatePromise@139695d9(incomplete)], command=(PING), params=[], codec=org.redisson.client.codec.StringCodec]]
```

We tried below points to investigate the issue:

- Restart the client application.
- Restart Redis cluster nodes.

Post these restarts as well, the same issue persisted.

We were able to resolve the issue by changing the ***timeout*** property from **0 to 10** seconds in server.conf of Redis. On reverting the *timeout* back to 0 also is not causing the issue to reoccur again.

Anyone else faced similar kind of issue?. If yes, do we know the reason behind it?